# Save Mono with reactive repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I try to implement a reactive endpoint to save new entity instances:

Method save in `SubjectRepository` is still required `Subject` without `Mono` wrapper. But how to extract value from the reactive wrapper doesn't clear.

Should I extract `Subject` from `Mono<Subject>` with `request.body(BodyExtractor)` and call `SubjectRepository.save(Subject s)`? Or I can somehow save `Mono<>` directly to MongoDB?

That is the right way to work with the input body?

Entity:

```
@Document
public record Subject(@Id UUID id, String route) {}

@Repository
public interface SubjectRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Subject, UUID> {
}
```

Handler method:

```
@NotNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> createSubject(@NotNull ServerRequest request) {
    Mono<Subject> data = subjectRepository
            .save(/** Somehow extract Subject from request */);
    return ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(data, Subject.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct the flow using reactive operators that will be executed when web flux subscribes to this flow. In this case use `request.bodyToMono` to resolve request body and the continue the sequence to construct `ServerResponse`

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createSubject(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(Subject.class)
                .flatMap(subject -> subjectRepository.save(subject))
                .flatMap(newSubject -> 
                        ServerResponse.ok()
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .bodyValue(newSubject)
                );
}
```